# How to make a resource file visible to all bundles in OSGi?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, equinox

I'd like to include a resource file (e.g. some xml config file) in my bundle and make it visible to all other bundles in the container. Is it possible without using the Fragment-Host manifest header? I'd like this resource file to always be visible in the classpath of all bundles running alongside my bundle, even those that do not exist yet, but will potentially be added in future.

EDIT:

To clarify - that resource must be available passively, i.e. the other bundles should be able to find it in their classpath, and not by refering to any special API or service of my bundle.

Some more background - my environment is a bit messy but I have no control over it and cannot change its existing bundles. The only way I can modify it is by adding my own bundles. That environment includes several copies of the `ch.qos.logback.classic bundle`. When logback starts up, it looks for specific XML config files in the classpath. If it doesn't find any of them, then its default behaviour is to print everything to stdout with debug level. This environment was previously used to host a GUI application so it didn't matter that much before, but now I am trying to adapt it so I can use some of its functionality in headless mode. So now it becomes important to me to be able to configure it in such a way that only warning and errors are printed to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no you cannot do this. Class-space isolation is at the heart of OSGi, but you want to put a resource in the class loader of one bundle and make it visible to all other bundles. That's not OSGi, it's the global application classpath.

The only thing you can do to add to the internal classpath of a specific bundle is to write a fragment which attaches to that bundle. A fragment can attach to multiple host bundles, but **only** if those hosts have the same symbolic name, i.e. because they are different versions of the same bundle. See OSGi R6 Core Specification, section 3.14.

You did however state that the bundles you want to attach are all copies of `ch.qos.logback.classic`. If that means they all have that exact symbolic name then perhaps a fragment will work after all.

Comment: Thanks Neil. Unfortunately defining `ch.qos.logback.classic` as the host of my fragment will not work in my case. This is because the other bundles include logback internally as a lib and have the `Bundle-ClassPath: lib/logback-classic.jar` manifest header. So, it seems the only way is to create several fragments - one for each bundle. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the classpath of other bundles this way.

What you can do is retrieve the classloader of your bundle from your bundleContext. You can give this classloader to another bundle to retrieve your resource.

```
ClassLoader cl = context.getBundle().adapt(BundleWiring.class).getClassLoader();
```

Another option is to give the other bundle the URL of the resource.

Comment: Christian, is there a way that wouldn't require any interaction from the other bundle?  In my case I have no control over the other bundles and cannot modify them. One method I know is by making my bundle a fragment of the other bundle, but in that case I have to explicitly define which other bundle specifically is the host of my fragment and I would need to specify it again for every new potential future bundle. If there there existed some kind of "general fragment" mechanism, then I could solve it once and for all...

Answer (score 1):

As long as the resource is on the classpath, any bundle can access the resource if it can get hold of the class loader of the bundle that contains the resource.

For example:

```java
ClassLoader classLoaderOfBundleWithResource = ...
classLoaderOfBundleWithResource.getResourceAsStream("org/example/resource.xml");
```

From a maintenance and API point of view, I would not recommend exposing a resource that way. Java types are much better suited therefore. Instead, let the resource bundle export a class that gives clients access to the contents of the resource.

For example:

```java
public class XmlDocumentProvider {
  public InputStream openDocument() {
    return getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource.xml");
  }
}
```

Assuming that both the `resource.xml` and the `XmlDocumentProvider` reside in the same package, `openDocument` will return the resource content just like in the first example.

Comment: Thank you Rüdiger. Actually, I'm looking for something that doesn't require any interaction from the other bundles - just something that would make the resource available in their classpath. Something similar to fragments but more general. I should probably edit the question to make it more clear...